# Asymptotic expansion of $\sin\left(\pi + \exp(-1/\epsilon)\right)$

Tags: asymptotics

I need to find the two term asymptotic expansion of $\sin\left(\pi + \exp(-1/\epsilon)\right)$ as $\epsilon$ tends to zero, but the exponential term is confusing me...

Comment: Assuming $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}$ the sign of $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ makes a big difference. Please adjust the title or the text.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, it does.

Comment: You've missed the point of gammatester's comment.  Is it $\exp(-\frac1\epsilon)$ or $\exp(\frac1\epsilon)$?  Your title says one and your text says the other, and as gammatester said, it makes a big difference.  Please clarify.

Comment: Apologies again!

Answer (score 0):

Using Maple I am obtaining

$$-{{\rm e}^{-{\epsilon}^{-1}}}+{\frac {1}{6}}\,{{\rm e}^{-3\,{\epsilon}^{-1}}}-{
\frac {1}{120}}\,{{\rm e}^{-5\,{\epsilon}^{-1}}}+{\frac {1}{5040}}\,{
{\rm e}^{-7\,{\epsilon}^{-1}}}-{\frac {1}{362880}}\,{{\rm e}^{-9\,{
\epsilon}^{-1}}}+O \left( {{\rm e}^{-11\,{\epsilon}^{-1}}} \right) 
$$

Comment: Writing $x=-e^{e^{-1/\epsilon}}$, this amounts to $$\sin(\pi-x) = \sin x = x-\frac{1}{3!} x^3+\frac{1}{5!}x^5-\frac{1}{7!}x^7-\frac{1}{9!}x^9+O(x^{11})$$ i.e. the first five terms of the Taylor expansion.

Comment: Hi @Semiclassical you are very right.  Many thanks.